# C++ CRTP and accessing derived's nested typedefs from base

Tags: c++, boost, crtp, intrusive-containers

**edit:** I'll put a github link here when I am done altering my design for anyone who is interested.

**Background**

I'm replacing a `boost::intrusive`, `intrusive_set`, with my own implementation as 64-bit compiled intrusive-set stuffs 3 x 8-byte pointers into my container nodes. my container has a limit of 2^16 nodes so I can bring it down to 4-bytes per node with 2x 16-bit offset ordinals (which is a 6x reduction of size).

In the example below `base` is the intrusive-set container. The `derived` class has a `std::vector<container_entry_type<entry_type> >`. obviously with this level of indirection I need to have a bunch of nested typedef's in derived, which I'd like to refer to in base.

p.s., the containers are for the AST of data description language. The contained elements are therefore small data types and 3 x 8-bytes is very significant. Especially so since the containers are used to validate data-sets in tight loops.

**The problem isolated**

I want to achieve the following semantics:

```
template<typename TWO>
class base
{
public:
  void foo(typename TWO::dummy & d);
};

template<typename DUMMY>
class derived
  : private base< derived<DUMMY> >
{
public:
  typedef DUMMY dummy;
};

struct tag{};

int main()
{
  derived<tag> foo;
}
```

But I can't access the nested typedef from the base. This is what clang has to say about the matter:

```
main.cc: In instantiation of ‘base<derived<tag> >’:
main.cc:9:7:   instantiated from ‘derived<tag>’
main.cc:20:16:   instantiated from here
main.cc:5:8: error: no type named ‘dummy’ in ‘class derived<tag>’
```

Instead I am having to do:

```
template<typename type_key>
class traits
{
public:
  typedef type_key dummy;
};

template<typename TWO, typename type_key>
class base
{ 
public:
  void foo(typename traits<type_key>::dummy & d);
};

template<typename DUMMY>
class derived
  : private base< derived<DUMMY>, DUMMY >
{
public:
  typedef DUMMY dummy;
};

struct tag{};

int main()
{
  derived<tag> foo;
}
```

Is this the only way to achieve my use-case ? it just makes things a whole lot more verbose. I suppose derived could also derive from traits to save some keystrokes.

Another choice is to not use derivation and to wire the logic straight into what is currently derived. However, I'd like to individually unit test base.

Comment: Why doesn't `typename TWO::dummy` give you the required type?

Comment: added the compiler edit message, I guess it's too do with the compiler not having seen the nested typedef yet ? ?

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Interesting, indeed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possibility (that might or might not save you keystrokes) would be not using the derived classes' nested types in the parent in some places. Eg. instead of

```
void foo(typename TWO::dummy & d);
```

you'd use

```
template <class T>
void foo(typename T& d);
```

For extra points, you could use SFINAE to actually limit `T` to the types permissible for the original variant. (Note that inside nested templates, `TWO::dummy` can be used freely - they are only instantiated *after* the whole thing incl. `derived` has been, so it works out. In the naive version, `derived` is still incomplete at the point of instantiating the `base` with its member functions, it has no `::dummy`, which is why it fails)

Comment: I think that might just work.... <3. I don't have the courage or fortitude to understand SFINAE atm :D

Comment: It's quite odd I use this technique all the time in writing functional code, and I didn't make the connection myself. A true sign to how diverse the paradigms within C++ are.

Answer (score 5):

Extending [@jpalecek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113878/c-crtp-and-accessing-deriveds-nested-typedefs-from-base/8113956#8113956)'s idea, we could make that template argument take a default argument. But you need to enable C++0x to get this

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstdio>

template<typename TWO>
class base
{
public:
    template <typename X = TWO>   // <-- (requires C++0x to have a default)
    void foo(typename X::dummy& d)
    {
        printf("%s\n", typeid(d).name());
    }
};

template<typename DUMMY>
class derived
  : public base< derived<DUMMY> >
{
public:
  typedef DUMMY dummy;
};

struct tag{};

int main()
{
  derived<tag> foo;
  tag t;
  foo.foo(t);       // <--- call the function like normal.
}
```

http://ideone.com/AXXdW

Comment: the "key" type in my case is the value type of what is going into the container, so it isn't applicable here. But for the sake of the type of problems(s) CRTP is applicable too a default template parameter might make sense in a lot of casses.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `traits` class. You can just use `type_key` directly in `base`.

You cannot, however, avoid passing the type explicitly to `base`. At the time `base` is instantiated, the typedef in `derived` has not yet been seen by the compiler (more exactly: the class `derived` is not yet complete — how could it, given that even its base class doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Their are more types I need access to , the example is contrived. I am replacing a fully std compliant container with my own, so recall that containers have iterators, and their are other indirections not shown in the contrived example above :D