# C++ and CRTP pattern implementation and compiler dilemma

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, crtp

I'm trying to compile the following bit of code, however there seems to be an issue that I can't seem to resolve:

```
template <int x>
struct count_x
{
   enum { x_size = x };
};

template <typename y>
struct crtp_base
{
   typedef typename y::count_t count_t;
   crtp_base(const count_t&){}
};

template <int x>
struct derived : public crtp_base<derived<x> >
{
   typedef typename count_x<x> count_t;
   typedef crtp_base<derived<x> > base_t;
   derived(const count_t& c) : base_t(c){}
};


int main()
{
   derived<2> d((count_x<2>()));
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled wth clang 3.1, the following is the error:

```
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:18:21: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
   typedef typename count_x<x> count_t;
                    ^
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:18:21: error: typedef name must be an identifier
   typedef typename count_x<x> count_t;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:18:28: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   typedef typename count_x<x> count_t;
                           ^
                           ;
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:20:18: error: no template named 'count_t'; did you mean 'count_x'?
   derived(const count_t& c)
                 ^~~~~~~
                 count_x
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:2:8: note: 'count_x' declared here
struct count_x
       ^
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:20:18: error: use of class template count_x requires template arguments
   derived(const count_t& c)
                 ^
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:2:8: note: template is declared here
struct count_x
       ^
5 errors generated.
```

I believe it has got something to do with the way the templates are determined at compile time and if they are determined as being a type at the right time. I've also tried adding "using base_t::count_t; " to no avail. Other than that, the diagnostic produced by the compiler has left me really lost. An answer or a suggestion on something to read about this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`count_x<x>` is not a qualified name (it has no `::` at all!), so it cannot be preceeded with `typename`.

Once you fix this, the code will still fail because the derived type's nested typedefs were not seen by the compiler yet when it instantiates the CRTP base. This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8113878/46642) shows some alternatives.

Comment: `It is an error to use the typename disambiguator when it is not needed` actually I think that is false.

Comment: @Jesse I believe it was an error in C++03, but stopped being in C++11.

Comment: @Martinho: I made that change, it now gives another set of errors:c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:10:24: error: no type named 'count_t' in 'derived<2>'
   typedef typename y::count_t count_t;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:15:25: note: in instantiation of template class 'crtp_base<derived<2> >' requested here
struct derived : public crtp_base<derived<x> >
                        ^
c:\clangllvm\code\example.cc:25:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'derived<2>' requested here
   derived<2> d((count_x<2>()));

Comment: GCC 4.7.2 was not sufficiently happy with just this change, and in fact I couldn't find a way to make it so.

Comment: @ildjarn yeah, this approach just won't work because the nested types were not seen yet at time of instantiation.